# How to text match the specific line in codesign so as to check whether its signed correctly or not

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, code-signing

I want to check whether a particular Mac app has been codesigned by my certificate authority or not in the terminal.

For that, I am having this code, but I am getting the entire codesign output and 1 at the end for some reason.

```
codesign -dvv --deep MayApp.app | grep "Authority=Mac Developer: My Certificate (5JFD6LWV27)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "App has been signed successfully by my cert!"
else
    echo "App is not signed correctly!"
fi
```

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `grep -q` to suppress output

Comment: Thanks for chiming in here @anubhava. I tried -q but it didn't suppress the output for me.

Comment: For short, I tried this: `codesign -dvv --deep MayApp.app | grep -q "Authority=Mac Developer: My Certificate (5JFD6LWV27)"; echo $?`

Comment: Try: `codesign -dvv --deep MayApp.app | grep -qF "Authority=Mac Developer: My Certificate (5JFD6LWV27)"`

Comment: I tried that as well. Still, same output. Actually, I also tried `grep -qFx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your `codesign` is writing on stderr.

You can this snippet to pipeline both stdout/stderr to `grep`:

```
if codesign -dvv --deep MayApp.app 2>&1 | grep -qF "Authority=Mac Developer: My Certificate (5JFD6LWV27)"
then
   echo "App has been signed successfully by my cert!"
else
   echo "App is not signed correctly!"
fi
```

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token '&' when I tried this line: `codesign -dvv --deep MayApp.app |& grep -qF "Authority=Mac Developer: My Certificate (5JFD6LWV27)"; echo $?`

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a ton. Can you please explain your answer? Sorry, I am not that expert in bash scripting.

Comment: Since `codesign` is writing output on `stderr` instead of `stdout` a simple pipe to `grep` is not working as `grep` is getting only `stdout` data from previous command. By doing `2>&1` we are first redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` and then `grep` is happy